# Error while using callback function with Article.findOneandUpdate() request

Tags: javascript

I want to add a callback function to my .put request. So when I use the Article.findOneandUpdate request it comes up with a error in my terminal that says :

```
throw new MongooseError('Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback');
          ^

MongooseError: Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4299:11)
    at _update (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4141:11)
    at Query.replaceOne (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4097:10)
    at _update (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3858:16)
    at Function.replaceOne (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3831:10)
    at C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\app.js:57:13  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at next (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:140:7)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Harsh\onedrive\desktop\wikiProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My app.js code is as below: (Please read the .put request under the app.route("/articles/:articleTitle") section )

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const port = 3000;
 
const app = express();
 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
 
app.use(express.static("public"));
 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wikiDB');
 
const articleSchema = {
    title: String,
    content: String,
}
 
const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);
 

app.route("/articles")
.get(function(req, res){
    Article.find().then(function(foundArticles){
        res.send(foundArticles);
    });
})
.post(function(req, res){
    const newArticle = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content
    })
    newArticle.save(function(err){
        if (!err){
            res.send("Successfully added an article")
        } else {
            res.send(err);
        }
    });
});
 //////////////////////////////////////Requests targetting a single article//////////////////////////

 app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
 .get(function(req, res){
    Article.findOne({title:req.params.articleTitle}).then(function(err, foundArticle){
        if (!err){
            res.send(foundArticle)
        } else {
            // res.send("No articles matching that title were found.")
            res.send(err)
        }
    })
})

.put((req, res) => {
    Article.findOneAndUpdate(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
      { overwrite: true },
      (err) => {
        if (!err) {
          res.send("Seccessfully updated article.");
        }
      }
    );
  });

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log(`Server is running on port`);
});
```

What should I write instead of the err function if I want to add a callback function under the .put request?

I tried changing the format of the callback function but still can't figure out the error.SO, please help me with this issue regarding the callback function.

Comment: Structure it like your get handler (using a then function).  Web search for that error message shows a number of similar questions with full answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will worked

```
app
  .route("/articles/:articleTitle")
  .get(function (req, res) {
    Article.findOne({ title: req.params.articleTitle }).then(function (
      foundArticle
    ) {
      if (foundArticle) {
        res.send(foundArticle);
      } else {
        res.send("No articles matching that title was found.");
      }
    });
  })

  .put(function (req, res) {
    Article.findOneAndUpdate(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
      { overwrite: true }
    ).then(function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Success!");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.